# Referencing <tmpl:myTemplate /> in grails taglib

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, taglib

I've created a tmpl gsp tag containing a bit of markup that's used throughout the forms in my webapp (/shared/formRow.gsp). I'd like to reference this tmpl gsp tag in a groovy taglib I've created. Is this possible?

Here's the def from my taglib...

```
def checkboxRow = { attrs ->
    def name = attrs.name
    def value = attrs.value
    def label = attrs.label
    def defaultLabel = attrs.defaultLabel

    out << "<tmpl:/shared/formRow name='${name}' label='${label}' defaultLabel='${defaultLabel}'>"
    out << "    ${checkBox(id: name, name: name, value: value)}"
    out << "</tmpl:/shared/formRow>"
}
```

I realise the syntax is a bit different in taglibs (e.g. you need to do ${checkBox(...)} rather than ), but is it possible to reference your own tmpl gsp tag in a similar way? If so, what syntax would I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that it's in the Grails documentation, [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#taglibs).

You should just call the render template method like this:

```
def formatBook = { attrs, body ->
    out << render(template: "bookTemplate", model: [book: attrs.book])
}
```

Simple really!